# Fetch the value of ID based on Date entered in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a requirement to fetch the value of ID with respect to the input date, falling in between the date range.

Eg:

- if my input date is 10-APR-2018 , the output should be 3
- if my input date is 18-JUN-2018 , the output should be 6

This input will be random/daily incremented/current date value.

How can I write some SQL for this purpose?

[image: Data in Table]

Comment: What have you tried so far? And where exactly are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following with `between` clause for date columns :

```
select id 
  from tab 
 where :dt between start_dt and end_dt;
```

where `:dt` is your input date value such as `date'2018-04-10'` or `date'2018-06-18'` .. etc.

[***SQL Fiddle Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b4194/65)